# Get all rows in database based on a string array with ID's and fill them in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to populate the gridview with the records that match the database ID's in a string array.

Some of my fields in the gridview are template fields with two dropdown lists and one textbox and I want to populate them too based on the ID's given.

How can I iterate through each element in the array string and call my stored procedure "SelectById" and then fill the matching ID's in the database into the GridView.

**NOTE : Don't need to worry about that stored procedure because it's working smoothly.**

**Here's my code so far:**

```
ScheduleToMoodleTemplate s = new ScheduleToMoodleTemplate();
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvEdit.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    string[] moodleIDs = this.moodleID.Split(',');
                    testLabel.Text = this.moodleID;
                    foreach (string ids in moodleIDs)
                    {
                        gvEdit.DataSource = s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSelectByID(ids);
                        gvEdit.DataBind();
                        DropDownList DDLScheduleType = (row.FindControl("DDLScheduleType") as DropDownList);
                        TextBox TbCourseEdit = (row.FindControl("TbCourseEdit") as TextBox);
                        DropDownList DDLDeliverType = (row.FindControl("DDLDeliverType") as DropDownList);
                        DDLScheduleType.SelectedValue = s.ScheduleTypeID.HasValue ? s.ScheduleTypeID.Value.ToString() : null;
                        DDLDeliverType.SelectedValue = s.DeliverTypeID.HasValue ? s.DeliverTypeID.Value.ToString() : null;
                        TbCourseEdit.Text = s.getCourseNameByID(int.TryParse(s.CourseID.ToString(), out var id) ? id : 0);
                        getScheduleTypeDDL(DDLScheduleType);
                        getDeliverTypeDDL(DDLDeliverType);
                        
                    }

                }
```

**Mark-Up Language**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEdit" runat="server" CssClass="list" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvEdit_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="MoodleTemplateID" HeaderText="Moodle Template ID" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Tipo Acção">
                                <ItemTemplate>                                   
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLScheduleType" runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Método de Entrega">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLDeliverType" runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Curso">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TbCourseEdit" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                       </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: DataGridView is a Windows forms control; this question appears to be about web forms?

Comment: My bad , it is only GridView not DataGridView. It is web forms. Already updated on my post.

Comment: You are doing stuff in the loop `foreach (string ids in moodleIDs)` but that is all in the same row so with every loop you overwrite the data of the previous one on the same elements.

Comment: @VDWWD Still didn't got it to work even taking out the code inside the foreach , can you post a solution for guidance?

Comment: `var mylist = new List<T>(); foreach (string ids in moodleIDs) { //add items to list mylist } gvEdit.DataSource = mylist;`

Answer (score 0):

Okay , I finally found the solution. The solution is pretty simple the only thing I did was use the method Merge of DataTable and this method can merge 2 datatables which in this case are :

```
dt and s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSelectByID()
```

So the final solution should be

```
foreach(var ids in moodleIDs)
{
  dt.Merge(s.ScheduleToMoodleTemplateSelectByID(ids))
}
```